# Will Apple reject an iOS App with external XML Content?

Tags: ios, xml, app-store, appstore-approval

I am developing an iOS Application which loads its content from an XML-file over the internet. Will this get rejected by Apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If it were to get rejected, every single application out there that interacts with Web services wouldn't be allowed on the App Store either.

Comment: That's a brave call given Apple's, shall we say, 'spotty' record :-) Sometimes, it just seems to be a crapshoot.

Comment: Spotty record or not, there is nothing stating explicity in the submission guidelines that you can't load content from the internet. Unless non-IAP subscriptions are involved, in which case it get a bit complicated.

Comment: IMO, it depends on where the XML file is coming from. Wasn't there an app rejected a while back for using one of the RSS feeds from the Apple site?

Comment: @j0k Yes, but that *is* actually mentioned in the guidelines. It explicity forbids scraping from Apple sites, but makes no mention of third party ones. (see section 12.1)